# spark shuffle write exploding on small, cached and actioned df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, shuffle

Hello Spark community,

I am working with pyspark, Spark  3.0.

I face the following challenge (pseudo code):

---

```
df1 #  90k rows, 10MB

df2  # 20k rows, 2MB

sql.shuffling.partitions=200

df3=df1.crossjoin(F.broadcast(df2)) # 2bn rows, few giga bytes

df3 some functions # use of UDF for ceja/jellyfish

df3 some filtering # results in a small file 400k rows, 200Mb

df3.count() #  to force execution

df3=df3.cache()  # to avoid recomputation of previous steps


df3.write.partitionby('date').parquet('some_file_name') #  this partitioning  creates 30-40 partitions
```

---

During the writing of the parquet file, a shuffle is called again and it is exploding to the roof, 300Gb Shuffle write. Which i don t understand as df3 at this point is small 400k rows, 200M. (the shuffle write is exploding during the computation of the crossjoin, but this is expected, if i am correct)

I am never able to write the parquet file, and get various errors like

> "No disk space left" or "Socket exception: connection reset".

Why is the shuffle write exploding on a small file that has been previously cached?
Do you guys see anything that you would do differently?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: caching must be called before ".count"

Comment: I'd say depends on what your UDF is doing.

Comment: depends on number of partitions of two sides of `crossjoin`, the output dataframe may have millions of partitions. try something like this `df3=df1.repartition(100).crossjoin(F.broadcast(df2.repartition(10)))`